# Storing fractions in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, fractions

What is the recommended way of storing fractions for measurements in the Ruby on Rails framework? I have a project where I'm storing measurements, such as 3 3/4 or 5 7/8.

I must be able to retrieve the values as fractions. Although I'm not opposed to storing them as floats, the primary concern would be retrieving numbers with the correct numerators and denominators. I also need to be able to query the database and order by fractions.

Comment: maybe this thread could help you: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=26052

Comment: Based on the article above, the suggestion was to pick a denominator based on the fractions you are dealing with. In my particular project that number was 16 because that was the smallest measurement. Then all you need to do is store the numerator in the database in an integer column. This works for improper fractions as well. So if you have the number 5 7/8, then you would store that in the database as 94. Great suggestion. Will be using it in this project.

Comment: Maybe a hint: use Rationals. Don't know if you can find a way of ordering or doing operations on them once stored though, but the advantage of them is that you can manipulate the fractions such as retrieving numerators or denominators for example.

Comment: another great article presenting various methods of storing fractions in a database: http://www.nullislove.com/2008/03/30/fractions/